# きのう奥さんの叔父さんて人から病院に電話あったの

Tags: translation, manga

海街 Diary volume 1, on page 8, this sentence appears inside a thought / narration bubble from the lead female character:

> きのう奥さんの叔父さんて人から病院に電話あったの。

After juggling with Google Translate, I believe the character is saying that yesterday the uncle's wife received a phone call from a man.

Then I am lost. Was the phone call made to a hospital? There is no previous mention of the uncle's wife being in a hospital. Or was a person from the hospital calling? If the latter then what's the に after 病院 for?

Comment: Here is that page from the free preview on ebookjapan.jp: https://i.imgur.com/gvBhTlG.png We can see that the voice is actually coming out of the phone (hence the bubbles are differently shaped).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> きのう奥さんの叔父さんて人から病院に電話あったの
>   yesterday the uncle's wife received a phone call from a man.

奥さんの叔父さん is "the wife's uncle", not "the uncle's wife". The て (or って) is a casual appositive particle (≂ という). 奥さんの叔父さんて人 literally means "a person who is the wife's uncle", or "a man who calls himself the wife's uncle".

So the sentence is basically saying:
"Yesterday, there was a phone call to the hospital from the wife's uncle." / "I received a phone call at the hospital from the wife's uncle."

<sub>The main character's older sister works at a hospital and is telling her on the phone that she had received a phone call at the hospital from the wife's uncle. The wife is their father's second wife.</sub>